# Is there any reason why `std::exchange` is not `constexpr`?

Tags: c++, c++14, std, constexpr

[`std::exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange), introduced in C++14, is specified as follows:

> ```
> template< class T, class U = T >
> T exchange( T& obj, U&& new_value );
> ```
>
> Replaces the value of `obj` with `new_value` and returns the old value of `obj`.

Here's a possible implementation from cppreference:

```
template<class T, class U = T>
T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value)
{
    T old_value = std::move(obj);
    obj = std::forward<U>(new_value);
    return old_value;
}
```

As far as I can see, there's nothing preventing `std::exchange` from being marked as `constexpr`. **Is there a reason I am missing why it cannot be `constexpr`, or is this just an oversight?**

Comment: Lots of algorithms could be constexpr, not just this one. Why don't you write a standards proposal to make them constexpr? (I'm serious)

Comment: Could you suggest a use case where having `std::exchange` be `constexpr` would provide a benefit?

Comment: Just wondring... if `obj` needs to be used in `constexpr` context, then does it make sense to `std::move(obj)`? Is it not *unmovable* then?

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, because the function doesn't have to be called at compile time :) If that is what you mean.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Then what is the point of making it `constexpr`, if it cannot be called at compilet-time?

Comment: Why would it be constexpr? What happens if you supply arguments that are only known during run-time?

Comment: @Nawaz I don't understand. It can be called at compile time if it is `constexpr`. I'm just saying that the function can also be called at run time, not just at compile time, and so moving instead of copying would be more efficient.

Comment: @Ron - Even if they are known at compile time, i.e `constexpr` themselves, it's still an implied `const` for `obj`. So the function is ill-formed if it's even attempted to be called in a context requiring a constant expression. Making it `constexpr` is just pure silliness. A definite red herring.

Comment: @Rakete1111: What I meant is that:  IF it can be called at compile-time then that means `obj` is `constexpr`. If that is so, then does `std::move(obj)` even make sense? Isn't `obj` *unmovable* if it is `constexpr`?

Comment: @Ron `constexpr` functions are not *required* to be evaluated at compile time. They *may* be evaluated at compile time or they *may* be evaluated at run time, depending on the arguments.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Indeed. That clarifies it for me.

Comment: @Nawaz Ah well no I don't think so, because you could be in a `constexpr` context, and there `obj` would not be `const`.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Any example that shows your case?

Comment: @Nawaz https://godbolt.org/g/79KfnA

Comment: @Rakete1111: Interesting. Didn't know that. Learnt something today.. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of the latest C++20 draft, after [the Albuquerque ISO C++ committee meeting](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4633.pdf), `std::exchange` was made `constexpr` with the acceptance of [the proposal P0202R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0202r2.html).

Comment: It's a silly decision IMO, albeit an harmless one. But that's the answer, so +1 for that.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why is it silly? Without it, making the move constructor and assignment `constexpr` in cppreference's [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) wouldn't [work](https://godbolt.org/g/JLSxWr).

Comment: @Rakete1111 - And where would you use this move c'tor in any meaningful way?

Comment: @StoryTeller You might have `constexpr` objects that you want to move, or even use the object in a `constexpr` function to do something, and you need to move it. For the same reasons when you would use a non-constexpr move c'tor, but in constexpr functions.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - An object *originally* `constexpr` isn't gonna be moved (the implied `const` gets in the way of that). Using it as a verb in a constexpr function, as you showed Nawaz, is however a valid point I did not consider (and I thank you for presenting it). I still maintain however that the utility of it isn't *too* big.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh yes of course :) Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Rakete1111: "*You might have `constexpr` objects that you want to move*". I dont think you can *move* objects which are `constexpr`. That is what I was saying (though I didnt know non-constexpr objects can be used in `constexpr` context, which you showed in your example).

Comment: @Nawaz Jup, did think straight :) Thanks

Comment: @StoryTeller quoting from Herb Sutter's trip report: "*At this meeting, the Evolution subgroup also provisionally allowed constexpr (compile-time) new, vector, and string*" ... if this is the future, you'll *need* move semantics to work inside constexpr functions if you want algorithms to be efficient at runtime too

Comment: I had to make my own and it gets used wherever you would use exchange but in a constexpr context.  so constructors and assignment are the two biggest